# How to access data inside the delegate of QML listview?

Tags: qt, qml

How do you get data that is inside listview. I have a QML listview that has a Textfield inside of the delagate. How should i call the text in the textfield inside the delagate of the listview?

```
    ListView {
        id:listview
        model: 10
        delegate: Component{
           id:component

           Item{
              id:item

              Textfield{
                  id:textfield
              }
        }
    }

    Button{
        onClicked:{

           for(var i=0 ; i<listview.model; i++){
                myfunc(     )    <---- textfield at index i text to be put here
           }
        }
    }
```

Upon pressing the button i would like to get the data in the textfield at specific indexes of the listview or in the example code all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is incorrect, you must access the data through the model, but your model is read-only, that is, it will never be modified, instead you must use a ListModel or a QAbstractItemModel.

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    ListModel{
        id: mymodel
        Component.onCompleted: {
            for(var i=0; i< 10; ++i){
                mymodel.append({"text": ""})
            }
        }
    }
    ListView {
        id:listview
        height: contentHeight
        model: mymodel
        delegate: TextField{
            id:textfield
            onTextChanged: model.text = text
        }
    }
    Button{
        text: "Press me"
        anchors.top: listview.bottom
        onClicked:{
            for(var i=0 ; i<mymodel.count; i++){
                console.log(mymodel.get(i).text)  // <---- textfield at index i text to be put here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: although i got confused on the approached you used at first, but now i fully understand :) in the project that i am actually making the model is dynamic. and i just increase the model to get more lines, but this approach is actually better